# Receber informações na página principal

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

Tenho um ficheiro PHP onde recebo dados gravado no firebase consigo ler os dados mas tenho que abrir uma consola do Mozilla Firefox para conseguir ler esses dados.
Queria saber se maneira de ler ou imprimir esses dados sem abrir a consola ou seja apresentar directamente na página principal.

Comment: Por favor, devolva o código que estava na questão anteriormente. Assim como está agora fica difícil de te ajudar e a questão corre o risco de não ser respondida ou até ser fechada por ser ampla demais.

Comment: Por favor, reverta suas alterações. O código é fundamental para que os usuários possam entender e dar uma solução melhor para seu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma [lista não ordenada](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) no seu HTML:

```
<form onsubmit = "return a();">
    <input type = "text" id = "name">
    <input type = "text" id = "message">
    <input type = "submit">

</form>

<ul id="dados">
</ul>
```

E utilizar o [`Document.getElementById()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) para mostrar os dados:

```
firebase.database().ref('SMS/').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      var resultado = snapshot.val();
      console.log(resultado);

      var lista = document.getElementById('dados');

      var linha = "<li>"+resultado.name+" : "+ resultado.message + "</li>";

      lista.innerHTML = lista.innerHTML + linha;
  });
```